# jQuery Autocomplete does not display with multiselect option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My script for `jQuery Autocomplete`

```
<script>

  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    {key: "1",value: "NAME 1"},{key: "2",value: "NAME 2"},{key: "3",value: "NAME 3"},{key: "4",value: "NAME 4"},{key: "5",value: "NAME 5"}
     ];

    $( "#project-name" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: availableTags,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project-name" ).val( ui.item.value );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project-name" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.key );

        return false;
      } 
      });

  });

    </script>

<form action="search" method="post" >
<input id="project-name" name="project2" id="searchbox"/>
<input  type="text" id="project-id" />
</form>
```

Output of the above script

[image: Correct Dispplay]

Works well, but if I have add the option `multiselect: true,` in configuration it does not display well and multi select does not work too.

Output if `multiselect` is set true

[image: Incorrect display]

How can I allow multiple select with proper display of tags ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to handle the multiselect in the `source` and `select` callbacks. Change your javascript to:

```
 function split(val) {
     return val.split(/,\s*/);
 }

 function extractLast(term) {
     return split(term).pop();
 }

 $("#project-name").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function () {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(", ");

        $("#project-id").val(ui.item.key);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Source: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple.html

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/bpx7gqt9/1/)

Comment: Does the script above converts data into tag format ? Also how can I call dynamic URL in `source` like `ajax_call.php` instead of `availableTags` ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy No, but you can use a plugin like: [https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) that will convert the selected values to tags

Comment: And yes, you can use a remote function replacing the availableTags. Example: [http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Comment: The tag feature is already present but not working with your script. Moreover if i use remote function, the url does not work. Can you pls update your answer with these two things ?

Comment: I can't see where the tag feature are. Using this plugin: [jQuery-Tags-Input](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) i build this sample: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/bpx7gqt9/4/)

Comment: To do a remote search you just need to get a response from your `ajax_call.php` in the correct format. In the docs of jquery.autocomplete you will find some examples, with the above plugin, [jQuery-Tags-Input](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input), you will find some examples too.

Comment: I have switched to `http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote`. The json data passed is in `[{"EMMPLOYEENAME":"John Doe","EMPLOYEEID":"123"}]` format, but the list does not show when I type something.